# How to place legend next to each line in matplitlib

Tags: matplotlib

Here is my plot, you can see that there is over 15 lines in a plot, although I put a legend in the top right corner, I still can not easily differentiate each line.

Is there a better way of doing this? for example, put legend next each line? I can not find a API. any help is appreciated.

[image]

You can

Comment: You can use `text()` or `annotate()` to place text at a user specified location. Please look at [the annotation documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html) and ask a new question if you have a *specific* implementation problem

Comment: The problem is that the data is dynamic,.

Comment: @scotthuang A general remark: it is best to ask your question based on a minimal example, that can be run directly (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you to isolate the problem, and will give the best answers. Finally, it results in a nicer reference for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment is indeed what you need. This post is just to make a solution a bit more explicit.

Using annotate a label can be placed at a specific position. I.e. it can be placed based on the coordinates of the last point of the curve, e.g. `(xlast, ylast)`. To make the plot more pretty, the horizontal position can increased by e.g. 2% to place the label at a small distance from the last point (i.e. the label is placed at `(1.02*xlast, ylast)`).

In a small example:

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


x     = np.linspace(0,1,2)
y     = 1*x
label = '1x'
color = 'b'

ax.plot(x, y, color=color)

ax.annotate(label,
  xy     = (     x[-1], y[-1]),
  xytext = (1.02*x[-1], y[-1]),
  color  = color,
)


x     = np.linspace(0,1,2)
y     = 2*x
label = '2x'
color = 'r'

ax.plot(x, y, color=color)

ax.annotate(label,
  xy     = (     x[-1], y[-1]),
  xytext = (1.02*x[-1], y[-1]),
  color  = color,
)


ax.set_xlim([0,1.2])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('so.png')
plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: ok, I got the point. I will try to google around, find if there is a  better solution. There is one problem for me to apply your answer, many of my lines in this plot is very close. So I need make sure the text will not overlapp. And your advice for how to ask question is noted

Comment: @scotthuang you might try looking into the `adjustText` package [here](https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText) which might help with the overlapping text problem

Comment: @tom, thanks. adjuestText works for me. sorry for the late response. some urgent work pop up.